# EXTJS TagField restrict user to remove item from tagField

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs5, tagfile

How i can achieve this functionality?
- that i want to restrict user to remove item from tag-field base on any condition - user can only insert new item in tag-field

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`beforedeselect`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html#event-beforedeselect) and return false for canceling the deselection.

For example:

```
listeners: {
  beforedeselect: function(){
    return false;
  }
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1j1k